# Create table and Insert to SQL Server using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a huge table (147 columns) and I would like to know if it is possible to create the table in SQL server from my pandas dataframe so I don't have to `CREATE TABLE` for 147 columns.

I am trying to follow what is answered in most of related questions:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP-LFOSSEF;DATABASE=test;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxx")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
df.to_sql("table_name", connection,index=False)
```

The `user` and `password` work because that's what I am using to sign in into sqlserver.

When I run this, I get:

> Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE
> type='table' AND name=?;': ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sqlite_master'.
> (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

If I remove the `connection = engine.raw_connection()` and use `engine` directly, I get:

> AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Any idea what is wrong? Do I need to create an empty table first? I've been troubleshooting for hours and can't find any reason why this isnt working.

Comment: Passing `engine` as the second parameter to `to_sql()` should work. What versions of SQLAlchemy and pandas are you using?

Comment: Using ('1.3.22', '0.25.3') respectively

Comment: What is `type(engine)`?

Comment: `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine`, don't know how it get to `sqlalchemy` though

Comment: That is the correct type. [This code](https://pastebin.com/QFwVZF0N) works fine for me. Perhaps your SQLAlchemy install is broken. You could try `pip uninstall sqlalchemy` followed by `pip install sqlalchemy` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this.

```
import pyodbc

engine = "mssql+pyodbc://Your_Server_Name/Your_DB_Name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"

df.to_sql(x, engine, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

df = name of your dataframe & x = name of your table in SQL Server

Comment: There being two question marks caused this to fail for me.  Change the second one to an `&` and it worked!